# Main python script calling base script using variables from main script

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I want to run external python script from main script but my external script is making use of some of the variables created in the main script so how do I handle this circular referencing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please read the tour and the guides. Regarding your question, I think you should use functions, and modules. What code have you wrote so far?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple script transform it into a function and then call it in the main script. That way you can pass some attributes.
like so:

```
def ext_script(attribute1, attribute2):
    print(attribute1, attribute2)

# your main script here
ext_script("hello", "there")
```

Comment: If a question is too vague to be certain as to whether an answer is appropriate, it's generally better to vote to close as unclear or too-broad rather than answer. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), including the bullet point about questions that "...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem".